# "git stash branch <branch>" prints "...would be overwritten by checkout"

Tags: git

My system got shut down at the exact moment that I was moving commits around and I currently can't run "git status", "git log", or checkout anything (after having run `git fsck`). The only thing that *I can do* in my repository is manage my stashes (which, fortunately, should be enough). However, I can't seem to make branches from them:

```
$ git stash branch dustin/stash1 stash@{0}
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    waw/config/order.py
    waw/order.py
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

Why would it be complaining about a dirty work-dir if all I'm trying to do is create a branch from a stash?

I fell-back to creating patches from my stashes and was able to mostly apply those changes into a fresh clone (using --reject). I was also able to recover some important changes by "undoing" back a copy of steps in my editor and bringing back the previous state of that file. However, I'd still really like to understand the above for next time.

Comment: Cautionary tale for all of us: unpushed branches are unsafe. Regularly push your work to the remote, so in case of local disaster, recloning is all you need. Not to bash you Dustin over the head, while you're already in a tricky situation, of course.

Comment: Does `git reflog` work? Have you tested cloning the repo locally, e.g. `mkdir /tmp/clonetest; cd /tmp/clonetest; git clone /your/repo/with/some/trouble`?

Comment: If you want help with something that's not working, consider providing details like a transcript of the command and its output. "Show the evidence you're looking at" is a rule worth considering. What happens when you run `git status` and `git log`?

Comment: @RomainValeri I had open work and was moving part of it to a different branch and then rebasing my work branch on top of that. It was actually executing the rebase when the computer shutdown. Not to restate what was already stated, of course.

Comment: @jthill I did. I was asking about why creating a branch from a stash would care about any working files (which I didn't have any visibility on, so this was decidedly unfortunately), and shared that output. Since I'm assuming that this is a not-frivolous step in the process of creating a branch from a stash, I'm looking for more of an breakdown of how that process works.

Comment: You said you can't run status, log or checkout at all. What specifically happens when you try them?

Comment: @jthill It complained about missing references and empty files. Upon closer inspection, a bunch of objects were empty. I'd share the output if I could. I didn't expect there to be questions about it.

Comment: Did `git fsck` complain? What files do the git commands say are missing or empty?

Answer (score 0):

You probably removed files with `git rm --cached` (or somehow ended up marking them as deleted in the index) but still having them in your working tree (or recreated them after deleting them, e.g. `git rm file ; git checkout HEAD -- file`.

If you then were to stash, any unstaged changes would be rolled back; in this case the file marked as deleted in the index would be undeleted/restored in the working tree. If you run `git status`, the file should show up; very likely as "Changes not staged for commit: deleted: file".